# Comparing with equals() method in Android

Tags: java, android, compare

I'm using the .equals method to compare a passed string (from another activity) with an int to show a certain image and I'm not sure if the .equals method is suitable. This is the code I'm using now. Unfortunately it doesn't work and shows the first image all the time!

Get passedID of chosen listitem:

```
passedID = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");
```

Show image part:

```
if(passedID.equals('1')){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image01);
}
else if(passedID.equals('2')){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawbale.image02);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 6):

Literal `String` are enclosed by double quote (`"`) not by single quote (`'`). Single quote is used for literal `char`. In your case, you're comparing a `String` with a `Character` (automatic auto boxing from `char` to `Character`), which will result in `false` result always.

This is how your code should look like:

```
if(passedID.equals("1")){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image01);
}
else if(passedID.equals("2")){
        image.setImageResource(R.drawbale.image02);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why you don't just put `int` as extra?

```
intent.putExtra("ID", 1);
...
if (intent.getIntExtra("ID", 1) == 1) {
  ...
} else if (intent.getIntExtra("ID", 1) == 2) {
  ...
}
```